# how I can get past this error while trying to use SSM to get on an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-02184d8ca315055d8

An error occurred (BadRequest) when calling the StartSession operation: The SSM Agent version installed on this instance doesn't support streaming logs to CloudWatch. Either update the SSM Agent to the latest version or disable the streaming logs option in your preferences.
```

Does anybody know how I can get past this error when trying to use SSM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options - `Either update the SSM Agent to the latest version or disable the streaming logs option in your preferences.`

1. (I assume that it should be possible) you can update SSM agent on provided instance using SSM Run command feature with `AWS-UpdateSSMAgent` document.
2. (Not recommended if you didn't set it up - it is disabled by default, so probably somebody turned it on for some reason.) Disable cloud watch logging here: https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/session-manager/preferences?region=eu-west-1

Comment: ``AWS-UpdateSSMAgent`` worked